# Google Apps Script taking too much time to publish

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Apps Script is taking too much time to publish in the gallery. What could be done to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are manually review these items in the gallery. We expect to reach to this script in a few days.

We are improving our processes and will be more responsive when our new systems are in place.

Comment: Hey Arun, when are your new systems are going to arrive?

Comment: Yes, I'd also like to know if a new system is in place. Currently been waiting almost a week for my review.